# Should I add an "over" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis

> Parks, woodlands, forests, jungles are areas where countless of living
>   organisms had made their homes. And where they’d probably live for
>   thousands of years. If we don’t send (over) our chainsaws first.”

Is the *over* necessary? (or maybe there's a better option?)

Comment: I'd use *send **in***. And there's no subject in that last clause.

Comment: @StoneyB Sorry. I forgot the we.

Answer (score 1):

If you just say:

> If we don’t **send** our chainsaws first.

it does not really say where the chainsaws would be sent to, though it may be implied in context.

But when you say:

> If we don’t **send over** our chainsaws first.

the meaning is the same as:

> If we don’t **send** our chainsaws **over** (there) first.

"there" being the "Parks, woodlands, forests, jungles" mentioned in the previous sentence.

Another example:

> I received your payment. I will **send** your package tomorrow.

does not really say where you are sending it to, while:

> I received your payment. I will **send over** your package tomorrow.

means the package will be sent to you.

Comment: How about using *in* as StoneyB suggested?

Comment: I wouldn't use "send in" in your example. An example that comes to mind using "send in" would be "send in the troops". But that is saying sending *into* somewhere, not from point A to point B, as in *send over*.